# sas adding 7 days to a date

Tags: date, sas, days

I would need to add to a date format variable 7 days.

The variable is creation_date and is like `01JAN14:00:08:04`.

I wrote this in a data step

```
sevendays_after=CREATION_DATE+ 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

but the result is like `1.70476E9`

and I need it like `08JAN14:00:08:04`.

Also I would need to keep only the yymmdd  or ddmmmyy and I don't know how to do this either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply a format to your data.

```
format sevendays_after DATETIME17.;
```

Or `DTMONYY.` or similar.

You should use INTNX, in any event.

```
sevendays_after = intnx('DTDAY',creation_date,7);
```

That way you don't have to do the math.

If you just want the date, and would like to discard the time information entirely, you can use `datepart` to do that (although that should only be done if the time part is useless, such as a date-stamp that is forced into datetime by SQL Server).

Comment: Thanks, it's OK the date, but I also want exactly 7 days after, I mean I want the hour and minutes also.... I did exactly the 2 first lines and I'm always getting every date at 00:00:00.